# How to read the Bluetooth Tracker to fetch the data about its coordinates?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I am working on App Concept which is similar to any Bluetooth device which works as Tracking. I need to use the Bluetooth and collect its location coordinates on every 5 mins.

How to read the Bluetooth Tracker to fetch the data about its coordinates ?

Where can i find the online materials to study and implement this concept?

It will be very helpful to have the details related to open source.

Comment: What bluetooth tracker are you talking about? What are you trying to do? I'm not sure this belongs on EE.SE.

Comment: Just like key finding ... there are bunch of bluetooth key chains in the market to track .. if the key chain is lost. My requirement is to collect the current location coordinate based on Bluetooth Beacon

Answer (score 4):

You can't. That's not how they work.

Bluetooth "tracking" tags work on a proximity basis. There is no location sensor in the tracker itself. If the mobile app is able to detect a tag nearby, it uses the phone's GPS receiver (or other location sensors) to make a note of the tag's approximate location.

Comment: Thank you !! My understanding from you is, Bluetooth Beacon will sent the sensor , which is read / received by another device. Receiver can be a Mobile Phone which has Bluetooth on it.

Comment: @goofyui No, I don't think you understand. There is no location information that can be read from one of these tags at all. They only transmit their ID.